# Watch console.logs in Cordova app with Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: android, cordova, google-developer-tools

I'm using Chrome Dev Tools to debug my application, but I have to go through `alerts()` which are a burden, said alerts being popped up o the screen of the phone. But how to show `console.logs`? They don't seem to work!

[image]

I tried several approaches with no success

```
cordova run android --device --debug --consolelog
cordova run android --device --debug -cl
cordova run android --device --cl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it seems that you have the log level in Chrome Dev Tools set to "warnings only" so `console.log` statements will not be visible.